# Stored Procudure SQL error in Node `mssql` package

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I am trying to recreate a Sql Server stored procedure in my Node app, which uses the `mssql` npm package. Right now, when I try and run the following query, I get an incorrect SQL error:

```
UPDATE
    dbo.C2980251
    RIGHT JOIN CFRTR...dbo.UPR10301 ON dbo.C2980251.BACHNUMB = dbo.UPR10301.BACHNUMB
  SET
    dbo.C2980251.UPRBCHOR = dbo.UPR10301.uprbchor,
    dbo.C2980251.BACHNUMB = dbo.UPR10301.bachnumb,
    dbo.C2980251.TRU_TYPE_ID = "132"
  WHERE
    (((dbo.C2980251.BACHNUMB) Is Null))
```

The specific error is this:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RIGHT'.

To clarify, `CFRTR`, refers to the db being targeted. All of the tables being used here are from the same db.

It's not clear to me what the error is here. How should this be written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE c
    SET UPRBCHOR = u.uprbchor,
        BACHNUMB = u.bachnumb,
        TRU_TYPE_ID = 132
FROM dbo.C2980251 c LEFT JOIN
     CFRTR.dbo.UPR10301 u
     ON u.BACHNUMB = c.BACHNUMB
WHERE u.BACHNUMB Is Null
```

Notes:

- SQL Server requires a separate `FROM` clause.
- Table aliases make the query much easier to write and read.
- A `LEFT JOIN` makes much more sense here than a `RIGHT JOIN`.  The database cannot update records that don't exist.
- `u.uprbchor` and `u.bachnumb` are going to be `NULL` because the `WHERE` clause only keeps rows with no matches.